# eclipse shortcut key CRTL + ALT + DOWN/UP does`t work in Ubuntu

Tags: eclipse

I have been using eclipse in Ubuntu system, and found that the `copy line` shorcut key of eclipse didnt work, I need that operation a lot, so anyone can tell me how to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ubuntu <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+arrow is assigned to changing the workspace. You can choose another shortcut by going to windows -> preferences -> general -> keys and searching for duplicate line.

I have it set to <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>, it saves a key press, only needs one hand and 'matches' the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> delete line shortcut.

Comment: This doesn't fix the problem; the standard Eclipse shortcut still doesn't work.  The real fix is here: https://askubuntu.com/a/380462/344227

Answer (score 0):

You can disable those keys in Ubuntu,
Settings > Keyboard Shortcuts > SET: Move to workspace above=Disabled & Move to workspace below=Disabled (by click>backspace>enter)

[image]